# Firfeox fails to find font depending on the order of font-family

Tags: css, firefox

If I use this in my CSS file:

```
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", Univers, Calibri, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "DejaVu Sans Condensed", "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", Tahoma, Geneva, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

then Firefox (69.0.3 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, KDE 5.17.2) finds the "Open Sans" font on my system and renders the body text using this font as expected, and this is confirmed in the Web Inspector tool (which underlines the active font):

[image: Firefox screenshot cropped to show that the "Open Sans" font is underlined in the CSS font-family list for the body element.]

But if the order of `font-family` is adjusted to reduce the priority of "Open Sans" so that we end up with this:

```
body {
    font-family: Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", Univers, Calibri, "Open Sans", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "DejaVu Sans Condensed", "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", Tahoma, Geneva, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

suddenly Firefox no longer seems to be able to find "Open Sans" and instead uses whatever its default sans-serif font is, as confirmed in the Web Inspector tool:

[image: Firefox screenshot cropped to show that the "Open Sans" font is not underlined in the CSS font-family list for the body element, and instead the generic font family name "sans-serif" is underlined.]

Is there some obscure CSS3 rule which explains why Firefox ignores all fonts within `font-family` even when one of those fonts is available and will work fine if that font comes first in the list? Or is this a known bug in Firefox?

## Update

As requested by [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) I retested with a smaller number of fonts in the `font-family` list, and the length of the list makes no difference.

But I did find something weirder: no matter how long the list nor how soon "Open Sans" appears in the list, it works fine until you position "Open Sans" after Calibri or Arial. If Calibri or Arial come first then "Open Sans" is never found (even though neither Calibri nor Arial exist on my system) and Firefox defaults to the generic sans-serif family.

This surely is not correct CSS3 behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the number of fonts listed from 18?

Comment: @j08691 I've done some further testing related to the font list, and updated my question.